# Segfault when trying to access a void pointer within a structure

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

Alright so I'm making a the vector data structure (or dynamic list) in c.
Here is my node structure:

```
struct vector_node{
  void *value;
};
```

and here is my vector structure:

```
struct vector{
  int size;
  int capacity;
  vector_node *start;
  vector_node *end;
  vector_node **nodes;
};
```

here is how I create and allocate the memory for the vector:

```
vector* createVector(){
  vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(vector));
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = 8;
  vector->start = NULL;
  vector->end = NULL;
  vector->nodes = malloc(8*sizeof(vector_node));
  int i = 0;
  vector->nodes[0]->value = (int) &i;
}
```

The last two lines is where I'm running into trouble. It seems that whenever I try to initialize the value variable I run into a segfault.

Comment: `vector->nodes[0]` is a pointer. What does it point to?

Comment: `malloc(8*sizeof(vector_node));` allocates the wrong amount of bytes (and also is symptomatic of your misunderstanding).  `vector_node **nodes;` says that `nodes` will point to an array which contains **8 pointers**.  However you used the malloc statement for an array of **8 vector_nodes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
vector->nodes = malloc(8*sizeof(vector_node));
```

is wrong. You need to allocate an array of `vector_node*` since `vector->nodes` is of type `vector_node**`. The recommended method for avoiding such errors is:

```
Type* x = malloc(count*sizeof(*x));
```

For your program, that will be:

```
vector->nodes = malloc(8*sizeof(*(vector->nodes)));
```

The line

```
vector->nodes[0]->value = (int) &i;
```

is wrong on several counts.

1. You haven't allocated memory for `vector->nodes[0]` before trying to dereference it.
2. You are converting a pointer to an `int`, which could lead to truncation of the address.
3. Type of `vector->nodes[0]->value` is `void*` yet you are trying to assign an `int` to it.
4. You are storing the address of a function local variable `i` in a `struct` that is going to be returned from the function. When the function returns, you will have a dangling pointer.

You need:

```
vector->nodes[0] = malloc(sizeof(*(vector->nodes[0])));
vector->nodes[0]->value = <some memory that will outlast the function call>;
```

Lastly, you don't have a `return` statement in a function whose return type is different than `void`. If the calling code uses something like:

```
vector* v = createVector();
```

your program will exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a two-level allocation. `vector->nodes` is a `vector_node**`, so by dereferencing it you obtain a `vector_node*`, which you try to successively dereference through `->value` to obtain the field of the real instance.

But how are you allocating everything? `nodes` contains *pointers* not the real objects, so after allocating the space for the pointers to the nodes you must also allocate each node individually.

So allocation should be something like:

```
const size_t LENGTH = 8;
vector->nodes = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(vector_node*)); // note it's vector_node* not vector_node, as we're allocating memory for pointers
for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
  vector->nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(vector_node)); // here we're allocating the real object

// now you can correctly have two chained dereferences
vector->nodes[0]->value = (int)&i;
```

Mind that the deallocation will require two steps too, in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

To work with your idea, you need to do a couple of things.

Change definition of `vector` as follows:

```
struct vector{
  int size;
  int capacity;
  vector_node *start;
  vector_node *end;
  vector_node *nodes; // <----- this is a pointer that can be offset like an array
};
```

Change the definition of `createVector()` as follows:

```
vector* createVector(){
  vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(vector));
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = 8;
  vector->start = NULL;
  vector->end = NULL;
  vector->nodes = malloc(8*sizeof(vector_node));
  int i = 0;
  vector->nodes[0].value = (void*) &i; // <----- offset the pointer like an array
                                       // <----- (which is what you allocated for)
}
```

The reason for this is that you have allocated memory for 8 objects of type `vector_node` and assigned the base pointer to `vector->nodes`. Because the memory contains objects and not the pointers to objects, you need to directly offset the pointer to get to the individual objects.